# write result in to a file, R

Tags: r, list

From my analysis my resultant object have this structure

```
> str(result)
List of 2
 $ HP:0000002:Formal class 'HPOTerms' [package "HPO.db"] with 4 slots
  .. ..@ HP       : chr "HP:0000002"
  .. ..@ Term     : chr "Abnormality of body height"
  .. ..@ Synonym  : chr(0) 
  .. ..@ Secondary: chr(0) 
 $ HP:0000012:Formal class 'HPOTerms' [package "HPO.db"] with 4 slots
  .. ..@ HP       : chr "HP:0000012"
  .. ..@ Term     : chr "Urinary urgency"
  .. ..@ Synonym  : chr [1:2] "\"Overactive bladder syndrome\" RELATED []" "\"Urgency frequency syndrome\" RELATED []"
  .. ..@ Secondary: chr(0)
```

How can I write this into a file? or convert into a data frame? Some how I manged it with the following clue:

```
bb<-result[[1]]
wh<-list(bb@HP, bb@Term,bb@Synonym)
write.table(as.data.frame(wh), "result.txt", sep="\t")
```

But I am looking for a better solution. Is there any built in function for this? Why I can't write it directly to a file? And what is mean by "@" sign?

thanks.

Comment: Look into `?sink()` for direct output into files

Comment: You have a list of S4 objects. The `@`-function is the equivalent of the `$`-function for extraction of elements from objects. You should explain the form that you desire for the file. Does it need to be readable in the same form as you see above, or do you want it to be in a form that can be loaded back into an R-session?

Comment: @BondedDust  I am trying to put bb@HP into first column, bb@Term in 2nd column and bb@Synonym in 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

This would be somewhat slow if it's on large objects, but since it builds on the format you already established, might be successful:

```
lapply( result, function(bb) {
           wh<-list(bb@HP, bb@Term,bb@Synonym)
           write.table(as.data.frame(wh), file="result.txt", sep="\t", append=TRUE)}
```

If you just wanted a version that could later be loaded into an R session there is a `dump` function that would create an object similar to what you would see if you typed `dput(result)`.